# how to delete all messages in telegram chat with python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot in python.
One of my bot functionalities is to delete all of the messages in the chat. I find the function `bot.delete_message` however it delete only one message according to message id and I don't have the ids for every message.

I also saw in the telegram api some functions that can help me, like https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.deleteHistory or https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory (will allow me to get the id of every message and then delete them). but I don't see how I can call these functions in the python api.

Is there a way to call these functions with the python api? or perhaps is there another way to delete entire chat history?

Answer (score 1):

Telegram Bot API doesn't have methods to delete multiple messages. You have to know `message_id` to delete it.

The methods which you've mentioned in the question are not part of Telegram Bot API, but they're part of Telegram API. `python-telegram-bot` library has support to only Bot API. You can make use of `telethon` library which supports Telegram API.